# Load category specific to device

Tags: iphone, ipad, categories, universal

I have an iPhone app that I'd like to make universal, most views can be kept the same, but there are some minor modifications that need to be made for the iPad.

Is it possible to load a category depending on what device the user is using?

Or is there a better way of doing this? A generic way (rather than specifically checking each time I create a new instance of a class, and choosing between 2 classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with some method swizzling at runtime. As a simple example, if you want to have a device-dependent `drawRect:` method in your `UIView` subclass, you could write two methods and decide which to use when the class is initialized:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

+ (void)initialize
{
    Class c = self;
    SEL originalSelector = @selector(drawRect:);
    SEL newSelector = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
                      ? @selector(drawRect_iPad:) 
                      : @selector(drawRect_iPhone:);
    Method origMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(c, originalSelector);
    Method newMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(c, newSelector);
    if (class_addMethod(c, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(newMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(newMethod))) {
        class_replaceMethod(c, newSelector, method_getImplementation(origMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(origMethod));
    } else {
        method_exchangeImplementations(origMethod, newMethod);
    }
}

- (void)drawRect_iPhone:(CGRect)rect
{
    [[UIColor greenColor] set];
    UIRectFill(self.bounds);
}

- (void)drawRect_iPad:(CGRect)rect
{
    [[UIColor redColor] set];
    UIRectFill(self.bounds);
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    //won't be used
}
```

This should result in a red view on the iPad and a green view on the iPhone.

Comment: Thanks I just started to realise this, its quite powerful :)

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` macro, this will allow you to branch your code based on the device type.

You may have to create a helper class or abstract superclass which returns the appropriate instance if you want to keep each file iPhone or iPad only.

Comment: I am aware of this, but this will make the code very messy. I'd much rather have a set of files which are only loaded for iPad users and overrides certain methods of the iPhone code.

Comment: I'm not sure thats possible for a universal app- obviously there's nothing that can be checked at compile time to indicate the device, so I think all code and assets are everywhere.